# object parented to bone does not stick to its place

Tags: rigging

I have attached an empty to the head bone of a rig.

This empty is the parent of a face - it has a nose, eyes, hair... attached to it.
(I did this because I need to toggle the face attributes in my animation).

Thing is, when I'm moving the head, the parented elements are not sticking where they should, it seems to slide and I don't understand why.
I DID have parented it in rest pose [as answered here](http://When%20I%20parent%20an%20object%20with%20a%20bone%20the%20object%20moves%20its%20place) for the same problem...

[image]
[image]

Does someone understand that or could have a look ? [Here's the blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sfni0sukquavovy/example.blend?dl=0).

Thanks !

PS file has been made under 2.8

Comment: Your headbone's base is in the same place as the neck's base. In edit mode move the headbone's base to the neck bone's head.

Answer (score 1):

Your rig uses weight paint for moving the body parts, whereas your glasses are curves with empty parent, which is parented to the bone - head.
Rotating bones causes them to affect the body with the weight used from weight paint, and the decorations are just parented to them, so body is deformed with weight (more or less), and decorations are just copying full rotation from it's parent.

So, when you rotate head you are affeting the neck as well, so weights are applied. However, your accesories use only head bone transform info.